# Error in htaccess redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The support team at my web host cannot seem to answer this question, so I have done my own research, but not 100% there yet. In short, I'm trying to redirect ANY page on a domain back to index page of that domain. For example ...

```
http://www.my-domain.com/images/xyz.gif --> http://www.my-domain.com/index.html
http://www.my-domain.com/cgi-bin/xyz.pl --> http://www.my-domain.com/index.html
http://www.my-domain.com/page.html --> http://www.my-domain.com/index.html
```

I think it's a 301 that I need, either a ReWriteRule or RewriteMatch

Here is the code that I came up with (line 3) and an existing htaccess:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^eco\-rainbo\.com$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.eco\-rainbo\.com$
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.eco\-rainbo\.com\/index\.html"
```

My limited knowledge of regex is saying "*if the HTTP_HOST variable starts with  "www.eco-rainbo.com" then ... "if next part of URL there is a forward slash followed by any information then jump to ".../index.html*"

It works - of sorts - and goes to the index.html page. However, Firefox complains that the page isn't redirecting correctly "... in a way that will never complete"

Must just be some small item I'm missing from code, but what?
NB: I tried a cpanel redirect, but got "my-domain.com/indexhtmlindexhtmlindexhtmlindex.html/page.html"

My Webhost used this - which looks almost the same - but doesn't seem to work

```
RewriteRule ^\*\.\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.eco\-rainbo\.com\/index\.html$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the destination you are redirecting to and use RewriteRule instead of RedirectMatch:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?eco-rainbo\.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.eco-rainbo.com/index.html [L,R]
```

Comment: BRILLIANT! Worked first time. (Seems daft that the web hosting support didn't know the syntax, but there you go!) OK, so minor prob that the images on index.html don't show, but that's a minor thing to solve. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Now got another "problem". The images won't show. Tried "/images/..." and "http://www.my-domain.com/images/..." but neither work (I suspect 'cos the redirect rule is sending those links to the index page) So next step, how do I "remove" / negate the images folder from redirect?

Comment: It's OK. I solved it ... and the answer is actually in your response, (For anyone seeking the solution ...) The RewriteCond with the "!^/index,html" is saying 'carry out next rule IF NOT index.html" So I added a similar line with "!^/images/.*$" which is 'IF NOT starts with "/images/ and has any data between here and end of line, then ignore tne next rule'